# R: how do I run a regression on a table with NA values?

Tags: r, regression, na, lm

Currently, my error statement looks like this:

```
NAs introduced by coercionError in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

This is the code that I'm using:

```
model <- lm(merged$Country.or.region ~ ., data = merged, na.action = na.pass)
```

I've also tried using na.exclude and na.omit based on some advice given elsewhere online. Am I doing something wrong within the lm parentheses?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide some sample data using the function `dput()` so that people are facilitated to help you? Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I will be sure to do this in the future Ric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your column is `Country.or.region` is a character, you need to convert it into a factor, and binary and use logistic regression:

```
data = iris
data$Species = as.character(data$Species)

lm(Species ~ .,data=data)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion

data$Species = ifelse(data$Species=="versicolor","Yes","No")
data$Species = factor(data$Species)
glm(Species ~ .,data=data,family=binomial)
```